# foreach loop where is the place of the closing ul?

Tags: php, list, loops, foreach

I would like to display all existing categories and all posts.

I wrote a foreach loop, but I don't know where is the place of the closing ul tag.

My code:

```
<?php
 $current_cat = 0;
 $curr_nb_item = 0;
 foreach($blog_widget as $row)
   {
   if($current_cat != $row->category_id)
    {   
    $current_cat = $row->category_id;
    echo "<ul>     " . $row->category_id . " ";    
    echo "<li>";
    echo $row->title;
    echo "</li>";
    ++$curr_nb_item;            
   }
    else { 
        echo "<li>";
        echo $row->title;
        echo "</li>";
        ++$curr_nb_item;    
    }
}
?>
```

Now I got this result in html:

```
<ul>1
<li>
cat 1 post n
</li>
<li>
cat 1 post h
</li>

<ul>2
<li>
cat 2 post x
</li>
<li>
cat 2 post y
</li>
```

I tried a lot of variation without result. I hope somebody could help for me. Many thanks.

Comment: I believe that between the last two `}`: `} echo '</ul>'; }`

Comment: not, I already tried this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the cleanest, but it should work. Modify the top of your if statement to look like this:

```
if($current_cat != $row->category_id)
{
    if ($row != $blog_widget[0])
    {
        echo "</ul>";
    }

    $current_cat = $row->category_id;
    echo "<ul>     " . $row->category_id . " ";

    // etc...
```

And then after the closing brace for your foreach loop:

```
echo "</ul>";
```